# Error 400 al hacer Post con axios

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de hacer un post con `axios` en `ReactJS`, pero me salta un error 400 cuando hago submit...

Por parte del back no hay mucho que mostrar, es todo por localhost el proyecto, está apuntado a una `API` en `.Net`, el cual creo el `Swagger`, y estoy apuntando a ese endpoint...

Básicamente lo que hago es crear el constructor con los 3 datos que quiero ingresar, un `changeHandler` y un `submitHandler`... el problema está en que no sé por qué tira Error, la url está bien, ya lo intenté de distintas formas hacer el post pero sin éxito alguno. Axios funciona solamente con `node`?

```
class AltaClientes extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: '',
            nombre: '',
            correo: ''
        }
    }

    changeHandler = e =>{
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

    submitHandler = e =>{
        e.preventDefault()
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'https://localhost:7079/cliente/agregar',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                data: {
                    id: this.state.id,
                    nombre: this.state.nombre,
                    correo: this.state.correo
                }
              });
    }

  render() {
    const {id, nombre, correo} = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name='id' value={id} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name='nombre' value={nombre} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name='correo' value={correo} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
            </div>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default AltaClientes
```

Probé de ésta otra forma..

```
const [id, setId] = useState('');
const [nombre, setNombre] = useState('');
const [correo, setCorreo] = useState('');

const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const blog = {id, nombre, correo}

    fetch('https://localhost:7079/cliente/agregar', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(blog)
    }).then(() =>{
        console.log('Nuevo cliente agregado')
    })
}

return (
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name='id' value={id} onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name='nombre' value={nombre} onChange={(e) => setNombre(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name='correo' value={correo} onChange={(e) => setCorreo(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

Pero sigue siendo igual

Puerto TCP:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:7079         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       21948
TCP    [::1]:7079             [::]:0                 LISTENING       21948
TCP    [::1]:7079             [::1]:55545            ESTABLISHED     21948
TCP    [::1]:7079             [::1]:59551            ESTABLISHED     21948
```

f12 -> network

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Uncaught (in promise)
> AxiosError
> code
> :
> "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
> config
> :
> adapter
> :
> (2) ['xhr', 'http']
> data
> :
> "{"id":"9999","nombre":"Juan Ignacio","correo":"Prueba@Alta.com"}"
> env
> :
> {FormData: ƒ, Blob: ƒ}
> headers
> :
> AxiosHeaders {Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', Content-Type: 'application/json'}
> maxBodyLength
> :
> -1
> maxContentLength
> :
> -1
> method
> :
> "post"
> timeout
> :
> 0
> transformRequest
> :
> [ƒ]
> transformResponse
> :
> [ƒ]
> transitional
> :
> {silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false}
> url
> :
> "https://localhost:7079/cliente/agregar"
> validateStatus
> :
> ƒ validateStatus(status)
> xsrfCookieName
> :
> "XSRF-TOKEN"
> xsrfHeaderName
> :
> "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> Object
> message
> :
> "Request failed with status code 400"
> name
> :
> "AxiosError"
> request
> :
> XMLHttpRequest
> onabort
> :
> ƒ handleAbort()
> onerror
> :
> ƒ handleError()
> onload
> :
> null
> onloadend
> :
> ƒ onloadend()
> onloadstart
> :
> null
> onprogress
> :
> null
> onreadystatechange
> :
> null
> ontimeout
> :
> ƒ handleTimeout()
> readyState
> :
> 4
> response
> :
> "{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-e205a758c13ff201966b3588831e4931-3fbae2fb871d808b-00","errors":{"id":["The id field is required."],"correo":["The correo field is required."],"nombre":["The nombre field is required."]}}"
> responseText
> :
> "{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-e205a758c13ff201966b3588831e4931-3fbae2fb871d808b-00","errors":{"id":["The id field is required."],"correo":["The correo field is required."],"nombre":["The nombre field is required."]}}"
> responseType
> :
> ""
> responseURL
> :
> "https://localhost:7079/cliente/agregar"
> responseXML
> :
> null
> status
> :
> 400
> statusText
> :
> ""
> timeout
> :
> 0
> upload
> :
> XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}
> withCredentials
> :
> false
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> XMLHttpRequest
> response
> :
> config
> :
> {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
> data
> :
> {type: 'https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1', title: 'One or more validation errors occurred.', status: 400, traceId: '00-e205a758c13ff201966b3588831e4931-3fbae2fb871d808b-00', errors: {…}}
> headers
> :
> AxiosHeaders {content-type: 'application/problem+json; charset=utf-8'}
> request
> :
> XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
> status
> :
> 400
> statusText
> :
> ""
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> Object
> stack
> :
> "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/main.79c9cd0a8002dd3e4545.hot-update.js:1686:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/main.79c9cd0a8002dd3e4545.hot-update.js:394:66)"
> [[Prototype]]
> :
> Error

éste es el swagger:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué sale al ejecutar en un terminal lo siguiente? ```netstat -ano | find "7079"```

Comment: El puerto TCP de `7079`, eso?

Comment: F12 -> Pestaña network, ¿qué ves cuando le das a submit?

Comment: @MarceloZárate ahi lo agregue

Comment: Pero cuál es el mensaje del error?

Comment: @AndresGardiol ahi dejé la imagen

Comment: Por favor agrégalo como texto (Al mensaje de la respuesta que te devuelve la API. Si la API está en tu poder (local) por favor loguea la respuesta del lado de la API

Comment: No es un problema de comunicación, el error es 400 bad request, en la excepción que dejaste te pone claramente: "errors":{"id":["The id field is required."],"correo":["The correo field is required."],"nombre":["The nombre field is required."]}}"... ¿pódes poner un console log de tu state y asegurarte de que estan llenos los valores que estas usando?

Comment: Probé tu código y en efecto el state está lleno.... ¿puedes probar desde postman enviar el JSON y colocar un breakpoint en tu API y ver lo que esta recibiendo? Y respondiendo a tu pregunta original.... No, axios funciona con cualquier api, yo mismo trabajo un par de aplicaciones con react axios y .net

Comment: "Por parte del back no hay mucho que mostrar" es justamente el backend el que te está devolviendo el error de validación, habría que ver justamente lo que llega, y por qué falla la validación cuando en el payload si se está enviando la data. No tenemos tu "back" para poder probarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directamente no lo hice con axios, busqué de otra manera y acá está la respuesta

```
  const [id, setId] = useState("");
  const [nombre, setNombre] = useState("");
  const [correo, setCorreo] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("https://localhost:7079/cliente/agregar?id="+id+"&nombre="+nombre+"&correo="+correo+"", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }      
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("Nuevo cliente agregado");
    });
  };
```

Comment: Claramente el problema no era de axios ni de react, al no compartir código del back, imposible ayudar. Lo único que cambiaste fue pasar los parémetros por query y no por body.

Comment: No tenia nada que ver el Back igual jaja...